# Added spaces between function arguments

Tags: indentation, cc-mode

I'd like to transform:

`function arg(a,b,c){}`

to

`function arg( a, b, c ){}`

Is there a way to do this or set it as part of *c style* auto indentation? So it will happen when editing JavaScript, C++, etc?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801983/how-do-i-use-astyle-within-emacs

Comment: @abo-abo thanks for the clue/answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another option for this is [clang-format](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html). There's even a Melpa plugin for using it: [clang-format](https://melpa.org/#/clang-format).

Personally, I bind `C-c f` to `clang-format-region` to fix the coding style for the currently selected region:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c f") 'clang-format-region)
```

Answer (score 0):

If [Artistic Style (astyle)](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html#_Bracket_Style_Options) is installed outside emacs:

```
(defun astyle-this-buffer (pmin pmax)
  (interactive "r")
  (shell-command-on-region pmin pmax
                           "astyle --pad-oper --pad-paren-in" ;; add options here...
                           (current-buffer) t 
                           (get-buffer-create "*Astyle Errors*") t))
```

*Reference*
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801983/how-do-i-use-astyle-within-emacs

On OSX I installed astyle with `brew install astyle`